# Como iterar con for en React?

Tags: reactjs, bucle-for

Tengo un problema al intentar iterar con un for en React, quiero crear una tabla con horas y necesito que "i" vaya incrementando hasta llegar al 23, que es la cantidad de horas incluyendo el 0, pero solo itera hasta llegar a cuatro, no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Este es mi ciclo for:

```
let numrows = 24
let roows = []

const ite = () => {

  for(let i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
    return roows = [set(day, {hours:[i], minutes:0, seconds:0}), set(day2, {hours:[i], minutes:0, seconds:0}), set(day3, {hours:[i], minutes:0, seconds:0}), set(day4, {hours:[i], minutes:0, seconds:0})];
 }

}
```

y así lo recorro dentro de mi tabla:

```
<tr>{roows.map((f, index) => (
            <th key={index}>{format(f,"HH:mm" )}</th>

          ))}
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tiene 4 resultados porque para cada iteración estás modificando la variable roows.

En lugar de esto:

```
let numrows = 24
let roows = []

const ite = () => {

for(let i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
   return roows = [set(day, {hours:[i], minutes:0, seconds:0}), set(day2, 
 {hours:[i], minutes:0, seconds:0}), set(day3, {hours:[i], minutes:0, 
 seconds:0}), set(day4, {hours:[i], minutes:0, seconds:0})];
 }

 }
```

Pon:

```
let numrows = 24
let roows = []

const ite = () => {

     for(let i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
    roows.push(set(day, {hours:[i], minutes:0, seconds:0}), set(day2, {hours: 
     [i], minutes:0, seconds:0}), set(day3, {hours:[i], minutes:0, seconds:0}), 
     set(day4, {hours:[i], minutes:0, seconds:0}));
     }
    return roows;
}
```

Aunque no tengo todo el código, igual es mejor declarar la variable roows dentro de la funcion ite.